# Is there a way to interact with a flash object from the client side?

Tags: flash

My goal is to build a program trader for the upcoming CNBC porfolio challenge.  I need a way to collect quotes, current positions and place orders in the flash object.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is quite broad for Stack Overflow. Can you tell us what you've tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: tell us from where you're going to collect "quotes, current positions and place orders".

Answer (score 0):

if i didn't get your question wrong then i'd say that you have a poll form in flash and you want to collect the polls from it ..
if that is what you need then you can either do it with php script that saves the poll in the database (but this sure requires some knowledge in php)
in pure flash world you can have that done via FMS(flash media server ) and the results will be updates instantly (even in flash you can have the results showing instantly be setting a timer that gets the fresh results ).

from my point of view php would be much better and easy for you to deal with .. especially that php has a really wide community and you will fined what ever you need ready and waiting for you to take and modify